# Automatic Uploader

Tags: php, linux, vb.net, automation, cron

Two years ago, I had the need to make a tool which automatically uploads a txt/csv file via POST to my Web Server which later is then parsed via PHP with a cronjob.

This had two happen automatically at midnight everyday. Although this worked, I cannot say that it was a flawless approach, as it was really stateless.

I am currently brainstorming and sketching on paper a new approach.

What will you suggest that I should do best? Any ready made solutions or ideas?

*Additional Info for the patient: So far I am really considering that instead of using cronjobs, I execute the parsing via GET/REST, as I'll be more in a known state like that*

Thanks a billion!

Answer (score 1):

Please note that `cronjobs` , `POST/GET` and `REST` are 3 different things and they do 3 different things .

A simple approach would be to use [Inotify](http://php.net/manual/en/book.inotify.php) to monitor the upload folder. When a new file is added its sends a trigger to a php file that uploads the files to your server.This way the file is uploaded as soon as they are created or modified.

Comment: About the mentioned technologies, yes it's clear that they are 3 different things, that's why I tried to utilize their strengths together... I will have a quick look to the Inotify. So far I am still sketching a design and anything simple or small might be of great help :)

Answer (score 0):

This solved all my hassles... altough I am still open to suggestions regarding the above post

[PHP smbclient](http://smorgasbork.com/component/content/article/34-web/66-accessing-smb-servers-with-php)